# make each submit as new java servlet call

Tags: java, servlets

My program is java web Application in which I get a ( search query ) from  user 
and send this query to the servlet in which in return , will send the query to a class that will calculate the index , and cosine similarity between the very query and index and send back to user interface. my problem is for the first submit it will work just fine ,  and I get the correct cosine similarity value , but when I go back and submit a new search query , It will add the new cosine value with the old value , in which will not result a correct answers.

how to correct this mistake , and make each submit as new servlet call or like a new java run List item or I have different understanding about servlets?

Comment: show us what you tried ? post some code

Comment: Without code it's impossible to help. I'd guess you're either using a servlet instance variable or keeping something in the session.

Comment: We cannot possibly say with any specificity unless you present code, preferably a [mcve].  At a guess, however, you are storing mutable state across requests directly or indirectly in instance variables of your servlet class.  Don't do that.  Use only the method parameters and local variables of your request-handling methods, the session object, or the request object to store request-specific data.

Comment: thank I got the solution , It was such a silly mistake that cost me hours .I was clear old content such as hashMap by making it null .. I got it by stating HashMap x=New HashMap();